# Add lines to existing file using Python

Tags: python, file, append

I already created a txt file using python with a few lines of text that will be read by a simple program. However, I am having some trouble reopening the file and writing additional lines in the file in a later part of the program. (The lines will be written from user input obtained later on.)

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('input')
```

This is assuming that 'file.txt' has been opened before and written in. In opening this a second time however, with the code that I currently have, I have to erase everything that was written before and rewrite the new line. Is there a way to prevent this from happening (and possibly cut down on the excessive code of opening the file again)?

Comment: Do not use "file" as variable name because it's shadowing the built-in file type

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you want to append to the file, open it with `'a'`. If you want to seek through the file to find the place where you should insert the line, use `'r+'`. ([docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files))

Answer (score 80):

Open the file for 'append' rather than 'write'.

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('input')
```

Comment: Note! This will not add a newline. If you need to add a line to a text file (as opposed to a line fragment), end the data with `\n`, e.g.: `file.write('input\n')`

Answer (score 21):

Use `'a'`, `'a'` means `append`. Anything written to a file opened with `'a'` attribute is written at the end of the file.

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('input')
```

Answer (score 0):

If having a `pathlib.Path` object (instead of a `str` object), consider using its [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) method.

```py
with my_path.open(mode='a') as file:
    file.write(f'{my_line}\n')
```