# How to highlight or add lines below a string in PDF

Tags: python, pdf

`PDFminer` can extract strings in a `.pdf` by converting it to `txt`.

I need to highlight or add lines below some strings in the `txt`.

1. Does `PDFminer` provide this function?
2. Are there any other `python` libraries for this?

Comment: *I need to highlight or add lines below some strings in the TXT* ... Actually, it seems you are after the highlighting of lines in the text after you have scraped it? Is this correct? If this is, indeed, what you require: 1) Highlighting is not possible in text format. 2) Adding lines into a `.txt` file or, in fact, a multi-line `string` is a basic operation see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10640804/4013571

Comment: I've also voted to close as this doesn't appear to be related to `PDFMiner`: There is no relation between `PDFMiner` and end-product text manipulation other. These are two separate operations and it seems as though you have no problem in the `PDFMiner` part.