# How Do I Save All User Inputs To A Notepad text File In Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.5

I've made a program for my GCSE Coursework and need some help regarding saving all of the users inputs to a text file in notepad can any help would be greatly appreciated

the code is

```
print("Use Yes Or No For Answers That Require It") 
from datetime import datetime #imports time package count=0 #sets count to 0 
    while True: 
        count +=1 
        if count >3: 
            break 
        name=input("what is your name\n") 
        yob=int(input("what is your yob\n")) 
        year = datetime.now().year #sets year 
        age=year-yob # sets age as a constant 
        print("so you are",age,) 
        user_input=input ("is this correct\n") 
        if user_input==("yes"): 
            print("nice") 
        else: 
            print("oops, you must be",age-1)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like `inputFile = open("inputs.txt", 'w')` and then writing to it? Are you using a library? How are you getting user input?

Comment: print("Use Yes Or No For Answers That Require It")
from datetime import datetime #imports time package
count=0 #sets count to 0
while True: 
    count +=1
    if count >3:
        break
    name=input("what is your name\n")
    yob=int(input("what is your yob\n"))
    year = datetime.now().year #sets year
    age=year-yob # sets age as a constant
    print("so you are",age,)

    user_input=input ("is this correct\n")
    if user_input==("yes"):
        print("nice")
    else:
        print("oops, you must be",age-1)

Comment: that's the code for the program I cant figure out how to save to text file

Comment: could you edit the code and send back the text file is named on my computer as data_file

Comment: I'm quite new to Python programming as you can tell

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your code example, with formatted code.

Comment: I cant do the formatted code as the school only has python in the IT rooms

Comment: I formatted it for you, your excuse is lame though.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have pasted, I would add the write to the statement where you confirm if everything is correct.

```
    if user_input==("yes"): 
        print("nice")
        with open('file.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write("%s\t%d\t%d\n"%(name, yob, year))
    else: 
        print("oops, you must be",age-1)
```

Although, you could put it anywhere. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640804/how-to-add-lines-to-existing-file-using-python) for a bit more information about writing files in python,