# while loop - sending output to csv file

Tags: python, loops, csv

This goes to a URL from the CSV file , then scrolls down.  I'm trying to grab the company URLs off of the page.  I can't seem to get it to work.  Now if I use just one stand alone URL without pulling it from the CSV, it will print to powershell.  Still can't get it to write to CSV.

Here is a couple of URLs that I'm working with:

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=Los%20Angeles%20remodeling
https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=Boston%20remodeling
```

The thought I had was that it has to be a loop within a loop.  Or, it could be `if`, `elif`.  I'm not really sure at this point.  Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_32mo')


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)


driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
username = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
username.send_keys("*****")
password.send_keys("******")
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
time.sleep(2)



with open('fb_urls.csv') as f_input, open('fb_profile_urls.csv', 'w', newline=)  as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    for url in csv_input:
        driver.get(url[0])
        time.sleep(5)
        lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
        match=False
        while(match==False):
            lastCount = lenOfPage
            time.sleep(1)
            lenOfPage = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
            if lastCount==lenOfPage:
                match=True
                for elem in elems:
                    csv_output.(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('href'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, so a wild guess: `open('fb_profile_urls.csv', 'w', newline=)` will wipe the file every time you run this script

Comment: see, that's what i thought as well.  But, through research  it's what i found in a solution on SO.

Comment: No, it _definitely_ wipes the file each time you run your script

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the file in write mode `open('file','w')` open it in append mode `open('file','a')`

Found in [how to add lines to existing file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640804/how-to-add-lines-to-existing-file-using-python)

Comment: this is almost comical that i just took it at face value that it wouldn't.  i know better. even after doing that it's not working. It's just a blank sheet after running

Comment: Silly question, did you repopulate the file with more data after you did the `'w'` and before you did the `'a'`?
When I run 
`fname = 'testfile1.txt'
with open(fname,'w') as f:
    f.write('Some Junk')`

the file contains

`Some Junk`

Then I run 

`with open(fname,'a') as f:
    f.writelines('\nmorejunk')`

It contains 

`Some Junk
morejunk`

Comment: i understand what you're saying.  And if i do what you just did, it works fine.  It has to be something to do with the loop.  I'm not quite sure if it's where i name 'elems' or where i'm writing a 'for' loop at the end to have it print to file.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Where it says `csv_output.(driver...` it doesn;t look like you're calling the `writerow()` function, thus not giving it anything to write

Comment: tried that...and it doesn't work either.  T.T  i've been racking my brain for the last few hours on how to get this to work.  i think i'm about ready to throw in the towel.

Comment: When in doubt, check your I/O...can you print `url` and print `elem` in your loops to verify that you're getting what you think you're getting?